# How can I Display a Progress Bar in mplayer?

Tags: command-line, mplayer

Is there a way to display a progress bar in mplayer (running without a gui)?

(I'm launching the mplayer command from the terminal like `$ mplayer video.avi` .)

Or is there simply any kind of percentage information like total video length, relation to already played chunk, or something like this?

thanks.:)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok. I figured out that one can press <kbd>o</kbd> button to toggle OSD (On-Screen Display) and that shows video length/played length.

Answer (score 11):

You can press `P` (that is, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) to temporarily display the progress bar and elapsed time/total time (it disappears after about 1 second).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use command line switch `-osdlevel <0-3>`

or put it into `~/.mplayer/config`:

```
[default]
osdlevel = 2
```